Threejs clipping cast shadow
I have a 3D object, a New balance shoe with a <directionLight/> and directionalLightHelper to visualize the lightsource, the issue is the shadow on the shoes looks weird, it seems like the shoes receive the shadow casted on it by a square object, I'm not sure if it's the directionLight create this shape? I'm using React Three Fiber. Here's the code:
          <Canvas shadows className="w-full h-full" style={{ 'background': '#201e21' }}>
              <PerspectiveCamera makeDefault position={[0, 0, 20]} />
              <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
              <directionalLight
                position={[30, 30, 50]}
                intensity={1.5}
                castShadow
              />
              <directionalLightHelper args={[lightRef.current, 1]} />}
              
              <Shoes
                currentShoes={currentShoes}
                currentColor={currentColor}
                position={[x.positionX, x.positionY, x.positionZ]}
                rotation={[x.rotationX, x.rotationY, x.rotationZ]}
                scale={x.scale}
              />
              <OrbitControls maxDistance={30} />
              <Ground />
            </Suspense>
          </Canvas>

Here is the result, you can see the shadow on the shoes on second picture, it's a square shape




Any chances for Sandbox?
